Postgresql docker image suddenly shuts down when trying to connect from another docker container
I try to work with the postgresql image running inside a docker container. The problem is when the postgresql server starts initially it seems to work correctly (up until the "database system is ready to accept connections" line in the logs) but then another container with my python application starts and tries to connect to the postgresql database and while that the postgresql server somehow receives the fast shutdown request. Also a log line from the main container with my python app (logged by its Dockerfile) initially appears in the docker compose logs (I use pycharm with its tools for it and observe the logs from the dashboard tab) right after the "database system is ready to accept connections" from the database container but then it appears to be overwritten by the following logs from the postgresql container.
Two services connected with depends_on parameter in the description of the main server inside my docker compose file. Also I tried both condition: service_started and condition: service_healthy with a simple healthcheck like test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]. So why can the running instance of postgresql so suddenly receive this shutdown request? And how can I stop it from shutting down so I can connect to the database from my app?
The example of log lines from the postgresql container (same log lines appear every time a new postgresql starts):
postgresql_db: PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgresql_db: 
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:55:37.945 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:55:37.945 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:55:37.945 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:55:37.951 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:55:37.958 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-25 21:54:52 UTC
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:55:37.965 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.241 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.244 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.245 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 32) exited with exit code 1
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.246 UTC [27] LOG:  shutting down
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.248 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.267 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.006 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.022 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/19716B8, redo lsn=0/19716B8
postgresql_db: 2024-04-25 21:56:44.271 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down

My docker-compose.yml file (I've also set bigger stop_grace_period because of my main app requires much time to start but I'm not sure if it helps as I'm not a devops engineer and don't know much about docker):
  postgresql-db:
    container_name: postgresql_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    stop_grace_period: 2m

  telegram-bot:
    container_name: telegram_bot
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - SQL_DB_ENGINE=postgresql
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      postgresql-db:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    stop_grace_period: 2m

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  postgres_network:


It is not clear why it is shutting down, and the docker file is not sufficient to reproduce/investigate the problem (no .env, no DockerFile provided).
